# How to make a menu stay in specific location. (Beginner)

Tags: html, css

I am making a website for my family and I am stuck on how to make the menu stay at a specific place. I want it under the picture so it looks better. Also when I am resizing the browser the menu appears in a different place and the picture resizes also, I don't know how to fix that. Here is my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    <title>King Buffet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
     <img src="images/LOGO.png" />
</head>

<body>
    <ul><a href="#/menu.html">Menu</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#/map.html">Map</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#/contact.html">Contact</a></ul>
    <ul><a href="#/order-now.html">Order Now</a></ul>

</body>
```

```
body {
background: #db2811;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 2em 2em 4em;
max-width: 500px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0)
}

img {
width: 50%;
height: auto;
position: fixed;
top: 15%;
left: 25%;
}

ul {
color: #fff200;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 600;
display: inline-block;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Don't place `img` tag in `head`!

Comment: Ohh okay im guessing its better in the body.

Comment: Yeah, no content goes in the `head` - only metadata and references/requests to external resources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```css
body {
background: #db2811;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 2em 2em 4em;
max-width: 500px;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0)
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}

div.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 position: fixed;
 top: 15%;
 left: 25%;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

ul li {
color: #fff200;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: 600;
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="http://www.logoopenstock.com/media/users/379/777/raw/e6d45448a69242d3c681de28cdd9b470-logo-design-download-free-psd-file.jpg" clas="logo"/>
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#/menu.html">Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/map.html">Map</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#/order-now.html">Order Now</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I dont know how you did that. Thank you it worked!